# Does freeradius supports PEAP V0 TLS method

Tags: freeradius

I want to test PEAP V0 (TLS) using freeradius server. Please let me know whether freeradius supports PEAP TLS method or not.

If it supports please provide me the eap.conf details.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, it does.  Both PEAPv0 with mutual authentication in the outer, and PEAPv0 with a TLS inner.  The default configuration should work for this.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRADIUS will happily do PEAPv0 with several different inner methods. Doing PEAP/EAP-TLS is possible. You have to configure two instantiations of the `eap` module and make sure that one is configure for PEAP (for the outer) and the other for EAP-TLS (for the inner).

The key to getting it to work is to ensure that the fragment size of the outer is larger than that of the inner.

I did a fairly comprehensive write-up of this configuration [on my blog site](http://notes.asd.me.uk/2012/01/20/freeradius-with-peap-eap-tls-for-microsoft-soh/) a number of years ago which you may find useful.

Note that there's generally no reason to do PEAP/EAP-TLS over just plain EAP-TLS. EAP-TLS completes in less packets, so authentication is faster. One reason to use both it to get the Microsoft Statement-of-Health data in the PEAP stage, if you are running Windows clients with the NAP agent started.